# Finding the angle of revolution of a triangle revolving around one of its sides

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, triangles, rotations

In short:
Let there be a right-angled triangle ABC with hypotenuse AB.
Let the triangle revolve around the BC side.
I would like to ask for your help to determine the angle of revolution using a revolved triangle (ABC*r*) with known angles (A*r*, B*r* and C*r* = C = 90°) and known lengths (AB*r*, BC*r* = BC, and AC*r*).
([illustration of triangle and axis of revolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76QzW.jpg))

For the context, this is a question based on [an orthopaedics paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0020-1383(15)30024-3) which proposes the following solution to the problem:
([image from the orthopaedics paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fK2qr.jpg))
([image illustrating what I understand that the paper suggests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olKd3.jpg))

**Update**:
I found an online simulator which demonstrates exactly what I am trying to illustrate:
https://www.geogebra.org/m/eSpdvEpm
check "rotate around y-axis", and rotate a bit => is it possible to determine the angle of rotation just by comparing the initial image with the rotated image?

Comment: The question in your title is not the same as the question you are posing in the text. Are we looking for an angle or a length?

Comment: Thank you - I changed the title to from "length of hypothenuse of a revolving triangle" to "finding the angle of revolution of a triangle revolving around one of its sides"